# React native - Hide status bar only on specific screens

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using tab navigation for uploading images like below

```
const Photos = TabNavigator({
    CAMERA: {
            screen: TakeCamera,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: focused? '#C7A985' : '#020202'}}>CAMERA</Text>
              <Icon name="chevron-down" size={15} color= {focused? '#C7A985' : '#ffffff'}/>
            </View>
          )
        },
        },
      ALBUMS: {
            screen: Albums,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: focused? '#C7A985' : '#020202'}}>ALBUMS</Text>
              <Icon name="chevron-down" size={15} color= {focused? '#C7A985' : '#ffffff'}/>
            </View>
          )
        },
        },
    {
      tabBarOptions: {
        upperCaseLabel: false,
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: false,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#F7F1ED',
          borderTopWidth: 1
        }
      },
        //initialRouteName: 'Feed',
      tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      animationEnabled: false,
      swipeEnabled: false,
    });

export default class UploadPost extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: null,
    tabBarVisible: false
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
        <Photos screenProps={{navigation: this.props.navigation}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here `<Statusbar hidden={true}>` hides the status bar in "CAMERA", "ALBUMS" screens as expected. But it also hides the status bar in other screens.

1. When I open the app, I could see the StatusBar
2. After I open CAMERA or ALBUMS screens the StatusBar gets hidden permanently for all other screens.

My question is, How to hide status bar only on CAMERA, ALBUMS screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**Screen Tracking Middleware**](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html) as mentioned in the docs to get the active `routeName` of the `currentScreen`

```
function getActiveRouteName(navigationState) {
  if (!navigationState) {
    return null;
  }
  const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
  // dive into nested navigators
  if (route.routes) {
    return getActiveRouteName(route);
  }
  return route.routeName;
}
```

*If the `routeName` matches your desired screens in which you don't want to show **StatusBar** , then set it to `true` else `false`*

Comment: HI, Thanks for the answer. Where do I need to add the above function? In app.js or inside index.js?

Comment: You can add it to the same screen where you define the navigator and pass `currentRoute` which can then be updated to check if it is desired route or not, check the [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html#listening-to-state-changes) for more details